# Segmentation fault の原因

Tags: c

以下のコードは双方向リストを用いて入力した数値を昇順に格納するプログラムです。

`void insert（）`　は　p の指す要素の前に w の指す要素を挿入する。
`struct data_t *insert_pos(struct data_t *p, struct data_t :*w)`:先頭要素 p を受け取り、
w の挿入する位置を返す。
`void printasc(struct data_t*p), void printdsc(struct data_t *p)`: 先頭要素 p を受けと

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct data_t{
  int num;
  struct data_t *next, *prev;
};

void insert(struct data_t *p, struct data_t *w){
    p->prev->next=w;
    w->prev=p->prev;
    p->prev=w;
    w->next=p;
}

void remove_list(struct data_t *p,int index){
  struct data_t *a;
  int i=0;
  for(a=p->next;a!=p;a=a->next){
    if(i== index){
      a->next->prev=a->prev;
      a->prev->next=a->next;
      break;
    }
    i+=1;
  }
}


void printall(struct data_t *p){
  struct data_t *a;
  for(a=p->next;a!=p;a=a->next){
  printf("[p:%p, bp:%p, fp:%p, data:%d]\n", a, a->prev, a->next, a->num);
  }
  printf("\n");
}


int main(){
  struct data_t *p, *w, *head;
  int d, count=0;
  head->next=head;
  head->prev=head;
  printf("State Input\n");
  for(;scanf("%d", &d)!=EOF;count++){
    w=(struct data_t *)malloc(sizeof(struct data_t));
    w->num=d;
    insert(head, w);
  }
  printf("State Remove\n");
  while(scanf("%d", &d)!=EOF){
    if(count<=d){
      printf("List does not have the index number:%d\n", d);
    }else if(count>d){
      remove_list(head, d);
      count-=1;
    }
  }
  printall(head);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Segmentation faultの原因は、kunifさんが指摘しているように、変数 head を初期化せずに使ったからです。　変数は初期化する習慣をつけましょう。　headはdata_tへのポインタですから、まずdata_t型の値が入る場所をmallocで確保し、そのアドレスをheadに代入しておきましょう。　そうすれば、Segmentation faultにならなくて済みますよ。

Comment: ちなみに筋違いかもですが、`for`や`while`の`scanf("%d", &d)!=EOF;`に違和感を持ったので検索したら、どうも「プログラミングコンテスト攻略のためのアルゴリズムとデータ構造」という本の影響らしき結果が出てくるのですが、最近はこれが良いという風潮なのでしょうか？ どうも悪い影響を与えているように見えるんですが。

Comment: `scanf("%d", &d)!=EOF` は、ショートコーディング（コードを短く書くことを競う遊び(競技?)）では、一般的なようですね。　コードは読みやすく書くのが、バグが出にくくて良いと思うのですが、コンテストとなれべ価値観が違ってくるのでしょう。

Comment: そうですか、ありがとうございます。対象分野が変わるとノウハウも変わるという実例のようですね。

Answer (score 1):

コンパイル時にエラーが発生していないなら、エラー検出とか警告レベルのオプションを見直した方が良いですよ。
あるいは作業環境を変えるとか。

Visual Studio Community 2019のC/C++では、まず`head->next = head;`の行で「初期化されていないメモリ 'head' を使用しています。」の警告とか「初期化されていないローカル変数 'head' が使用されます」のエラーとなっています。

つまり`head`の領域を確保していないのに、そのアドレスを使ったために発生しているのでしょう。

---

アルゴリズムを学ぶ・試すのも大事ですが、基本的なことをおろそかにしていては、簡単なところでつまずいて無駄な時間が掛かるばかりです。

全部が正解かは怪しいですし、時間が経過して変化してしまうことも多いのですが、
以下のような記事を探して書かれていることを読んで心がけるようにしましょう。

[C言語のバグ回避をするための習慣](https://qiita.com/Ki4mTaria/items/b6ab0bcbe9c87d4dc071)
[C言語のバグ回避をするための習慣：私の場合](https://eel3.hatenablog.com/entry/20150201/1422764793)
[第4回 C言語のテクニカルバグ](https://www.soum.co.jp/misc/programmer/4/)
[私はC言語を知らない](https://postd.cc/i-do-not-know-c/)